# Proper functioning of 'Save file' in Notepad program in C#

Tags: c#, file, save, notepad

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    public string contents = string.Empty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Untitled";
    }

    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text != contents)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do You want to save the changes made to " + this.Text, "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                sfd.Title = "Save";
                if (SaveFile() == 0)
                    return;
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = "";
                    this.Text = "Untitled";
                }
                contents = "";
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "";
                this.Text = "Untitled";
                contents = "";
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "Untitled";
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
            contents = "";
        }

    }
    private int SaveFile()
    {
        sfd.Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt";
        sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            contents = richTextBox1.Text;
            if (this.Text == "Untitled")
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            else
            {
                sfd.FileName = this.Text;
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
            this.Text = sfd.FileName;
            return 1;
        }


    }
    private void OpenFile()
    {
        ofd.Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            richTextBox1.Focus();
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            this.Text = ofd.FileName;
            contents = richTextBox1.Text;
        }
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text != contents)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do You want to save the changes made to " + this.Text, "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveFile();
                OpenFile();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                OpenFile();
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
            OpenFile();
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFile();
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sfd.Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt";
        sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            richTextBox1.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            contents = richTextBox1.Text;
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            this.Text = sfd.FileName;
        }            
    }
```

When we open Windows notepad application then open a file, changes it contents and save it, it simply gets saved without opening the Save File dialog. But in the notepad program I have created above the Save File dialog opens on clicking 'Save' after changing the contents of saved file. Although the same file name appears in the save file dialog but on clicking 'Save' it gives a message "The same file name already exists. Do you want to replace it?". That is what I want to remove and make the changed contents saved directly to the opened file without opening the save file dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Set sfd.OverwritePrompt = false any time after construction and before ShowDialog to suppress the overwrite warning.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have two choices to save: A 'Save As..' button and a 'Save' button. You can create a `string` to hold the path of the opened file. The location may also change if the user specifies a new location when they save the file. If the user did not open the file, the 'Save As...' button would open the regular Save File Dialog. Once the user specifies the location of their document, you can save the file path to that string and use a `StreamWriter' to save it without the dialog:

```
...
using System.IO;
...

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    public string contents = string.Empty;

    //string to hold file location
    string currentFileLoc;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Untitled";
    }

    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text != contents)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do You want to save the changes made to " + this.Text, "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                sfd.Title = "Save";
                if (SaveFile() == 0)
                    return;
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = "";
                    this.Text = "Untitled";
                }
                contents = "";
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "";
                this.Text = "Untitled";
                contents = "";
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "Untitled";
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
            contents = "";
        }

    }
    private int SaveFile()
    {
        sfd.Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt";
        sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            contents = richTextBox1.Text;
            if (this.Text == "Untitled")
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            else
            {
                sfd.FileName = this.Text;
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
            this.Text = sfd.FileName;
            //
            currentFileLoc = sfd.FileName;
            return 1;
        }


    }
    private void OpenFile()
    {
        ofd.Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            richTextBox1.Focus();
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            this.Text = ofd.FileName;
            contents = richTextBox1.Text;
        }

        currentFileLoc = ofd.FileName;
        this.Text = currentFileLoc;
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text != contents)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do You want to save the changes made to " + this.Text, "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveFile();
                OpenFile();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                OpenFile();
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
            OpenFile();
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Save();
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFile();            
    }

    //new method
    private void Save()
    {
        if (currentFileLoc != null)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(currentFileLoc))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        else
          saveFile();
     }
 }
```

I suggest you also enclose the `using(...){ }` block in a `try/catch` statement and handle any exceptions.

Comment: Sorry But its not solving my problem.. What I want is that the contents changed in an already open file is saved to the file without opening the 'save file dialog' on clicking the 'Save' button..

Comment: But thanks for the idea of streamwriter.. I got the point and made the working correct..

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is save the filename entered, then, when the save option is pressed, check for a previously entered filename.  If you have one, skip showing the dialog and just execute the save code.