# How to add PAGESET UP, FIND, REPLACE Dialog Box in C# code for Notepad Application

Tags: c#

Page setup, Find, Replace Dialog boxes are not available in Toolbox (Visual Studio) to develop Notepad in C#

what namespaces i have to using?
where & how can i find the above mentioned Dialog boxes?

Answer (score 0):

**And again**
OP was asking for on new / save as or dispose functionality.

[Link to functionality.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661849/proper-functioning-of-save-file-in-notepad-program-in-c-sharp)

**Edited post**
Edited due to a vague question.

[How to create menus](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p1.html)

How to do it programmatically and adding the functionality to make those things work is more complicated and will involve more sub systems.

[Step by step guide on creating a "notepad" application](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-create-a-Notepad-in-VS-C/?ALLSTEPS)

**Original Post:**

[All the information you need on default dialogs in winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa969773(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Create your own programmatically (intro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569489/easiest-way-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-which-returns-a-value)

Or just create your own using forms.

Comment: Ok that is a menu strip which is in visual studio, but you're going to have to program the functionality yourself. Example of how to set it up : http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p1.html

Comment: i need functionality c# code for NEW menuItem like...... when we click on NEW..........first it has check whether there is text in the richTextBox or not?...............next if the text is from an old file then save to same location .............if new text then save to saveDialog box...............if no text then directly open new document.

Comment: Then be more clear in your OP and your responses. What have you tried? Because unless you've actually tried something you're not likely to get help.

Comment: but i'll be nice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661849/proper-functioning-of-save-file-in-notepad-program-in-c-sharp the fucntionality is contained with that thread. Read it and use google, took me two seconds to find. And yes its there.. may not be in your face obvious, but it's there.